# UNITY/Vuforia Question: Click Button Take Screenshot Save to Gallery iOS/Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, screenshot, native, vuforia, toolkit

Complete coding newbie trying to do this.

I created a button in my scene and I need to now find a C# script that will allow me to call OnClick --> take screenshot --> save it to gallery in iOS/Android. I've been looking all over the Internet and I've seen bits and pieces of how to do this, but nothing complete.

I found this: https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeGallery

but utterly confused about what code I need so that I can drag it onto the button. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: There's a complete example on the page you linked. What part of it do you not understand? It's very simple.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I downloaded the assets and imported into my project.. I looked at the sample code, but not sure how to change it to fit my needs. Also, is this the code that I should be dragging onto the button?